# Extracting random point coordinates using ArcGIS 10 model builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I have a question about using model builder in ArcGIS 10.1.
In my model, I am creating a processing extent, and within that I am creating a random point to be used in further processing.
This model is iterative, and for each iteration, I am creating a new random point (effectively overwriting the values for the point).
What I would like to be able to do is to write the x-y coordinates of these random points off to a file before the next iteration is performed (either all together or as separate files for each point).
In a way, what I want is the inverse of the "Get Cell Value" tool and to be able to write that value to a file.
I guess it wouldn't be too difficult in python, but I was hoping to be able to do this in model builder.

Comment: How are you creating this random point, is it some python script generating an XY value?

Comment: Would producing a shapefile for every random point suffice, or do you need tabular data?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that at each iteration, you append the current random point to an already existing point featureclass. After, you could add XY coordinates and export the result.

Hopes this helps!

Comment: or (if the locations are independent) you create a feature class with all your points and you iterate through it.